# what does a critical number is doing for a function??

Tags: real-analysis, functions

what does a critical number is doing for a function?

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function. And $a$ is a critical number.
(ie, $f'(a)=0$).

Then can you always predict that this point $(a,f(a))$ will change nature of the function from Increasing to Decreasing(or Decreasing to Increasing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the definition of critical number - it involves the derivative.  If the derivative (or slope) of a function is negative, the function is decreasing.  If the derivative (or slope) of a function is positive, the function is increasing. So at a critical number, the slope is zero.  Does this guarantee the slope is changing from positive to negative (or vice versa)?

As an example, think about the function $f(x) = x^3$.  Does it have a critical number?  Is the function switching from increasing to decreasing or decreasing to increasing at the critical number?

Comment: yes..you are right...@fullyhip